# Beginner: Want to navigate from one page to another page in Angularjs 4

Tags: angular, web-applications, angular-routing

Please help me to understand how I can navigate one page to another in angular. Here what I have done.

1. I create a project (ng create)
2. Added two components (Home and About)
3. Add a app-routing.module.ts file and int file I write this code

   ```
   import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
   import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
   import { HomeComponent }  from './home/home.component';
   import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';

   const routes: Routes = [
           { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
           {path:'about', component: AboutUsComponent}
   ];
   @NgModule({
     imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
     exports: [ RouterModule ]
   })
   export class AppRoutingModule{ }
   ```
4. In app.module.ts

   ```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
   import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
   import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

   @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AboutUsComponent
     ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      AppRoutingModule
   ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```

when I am typing http://localhost:4200/home or http://localhost:4200/about it is not navigating.

Thanks

Comment: have you included ``<router-outlet></router-outlet>`` ?

Comment: No, where I need to include this?

Comment: Thank you CruelEngine Added and its working. :)

Comment: Enjoy Angular :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `AppComponent` markup file. This will let you to load `HomeComponent` or `AboutUsComponent` in the `AppComponent` view and make navigation work.

```
app.component.html

<h1> App Component </h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thanks, man you are awesome. Thank you very much. it's working now. :)

Answer (score 1):

also use `<router-outlet>` and `redirectTo`.

> app.component.html

```
<h1> App Component </h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        {path:'about', component: AboutUsComponent}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to html

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" >
  link to user component
</a>
```

the component will be loaded in the default outlet you can also create custom outlet